# Elasticsearch: Order items based on distance to point A but show distance calculated from point B

Tags: java, elasticsearch

Situation:
A Elasticsearch map full of Geopoints.

I want the points sorted by their distance to a location A, but need their distance to my location B.
Like "Show me people close to New York and their distance to me"

What i got so far:

```
// filterquery is a simple matchall() filter
FilteredQueryBuilder filteredQuery = QueryBuilders.filteredQuery(
        filterquery,
        FilterBuilders.geoDistanceRangeFilter("location")
        );


SearchResponse search = client.prepareSearch("myindex")
        .setTypes("user")
        .setQuery(filteredQuery)
        .addSort(SortBuilders.geoDistanceSort("location")
                .point(newyork_lat, newyork_lon)
                .unit(DistanceUnit.KILOMETERS)
                .order(SortOrder.ASC))
        .execute()
        .actionGet();
```

This will just show me all users close to New York, but the distance is ofc still calculated to New York, not to me.
I think i need some sort of aggregation, but i dont get it right.
Where do i need to put myLocation.lat and myLocation.lon?

Answer (score 0):

I would say the best option would be to use [script field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/search-request-script-fields.html) to compute the distance from your referral point.

Something like below should give you what you are looking for

```
{
  "script_fields": {
    "distanceFromMe": {
      "script": "doc['location'].distanceInKm(lat, lon)"
    }
  }
}
```

You can learn more on scripting [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.0/modules-scripting.html) and [here](https://qbox.io/blog/logging-and-scripted_fields-in-elasticsearch)..

Comment: how can i do that in java..?